# Running Tor first time

Tags: linux, torcheck

I am using Kali Linux. I came across Tor and installed it via terminal and then stated it typing "service tor start" in terminal. Is Tor now configured to all my browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not do it before, you must manually set an option to use a proxy server in your browser. How to set it, depends on the browser you choose. You always can check your status on [this page](https://check.torproject.org).